# How to set the cache for the built-in SimplePie feed parser?

Tags: rss, cache, simplepie, feed

I'm using the built-in SimplePie, AKA `fetch_feed()`, to retrieve a feed, and I want to be able to adjust the cache time from an admin menu. [SimplePie](http://simplepie.org/wiki/) itself is well documented, but not so much the WordPress implementation of it.

Any thoughts on the best way to set the cache duration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cache duration value (defaults to 43200 seconds) is set when feed object is generated and passed through `wp_feed_cache_transient_lifetime` filter with additional argument being feed URL.

This allows to conveniently filter it both globally and for specific feeds.

See [fetch_feed() source](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.0.1/wp-includes/feed.php#L522) for this and other hooks you can use to modify its behavior.

Comment: I love it when the only documentation is the source! Yay! <sarcasm />

Comment: Ha ha. I notice that you asked the same question last year http://www.wptavern.com/forum/troubleshooting/767-setting-cache-duration-simplepie-wordpress.html :)

Comment: Learn and spread the knowledge. :)

Answer (score 1):

To elaborate on Rarst's solutuion. I've been using the following to great success:

```
add_filter( 'wp_feed_cache_transient_lifetime', create_function( '$a', 'return 3600;' ) );
```

This sets the feed cache at one hour and should be placed immediately after the feed.php include.